# VB.Net: How to solve Request Timeout when loading huge records?

Tags: vb.net, performance, request, timeout

I'm just new on this approach. I'm getting Request Timeout error when I load records and put it a Data Table. I used SP for query and it runs less than a second when I tested it. But could not do it in my page.

items.vbhtml

```
<div class="pnl_viewlist">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h5>Product List</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="tbl_items" class="table table-responsive">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-light">
                                    <th class="text-center">Image</th>
                                    <th>Item</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Unit</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

items controller

```
Function items_view() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function

<HttpPost>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Function product_catalog(obj As masters.Items) As JsonResult 'function name
    Dim product_catalog_in = ws_masters.items_in_up(obj, Session("company_no"), Session("user_id"), Session("user_group_title")) 'from asmx
    Return Json(product_catalog_in, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function

<HttpGet>
Function item_code_view_sel() As JsonResult
    Dim item_code As New List(Of masters.items)(ws_masters.item_code_sel_view())
    Return Json(item_code, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function

<HttpGet>
Function item_list(item_id As Int32) As JsonResult
    Dim items As New List(Of masters.items)(ws_masters.item_view_sel(item_id, Session("company_no")))
    Return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function

<HttpPost>
Public Function upload_item_image(item_id As Int32) As JsonResult
    Dim _url_file_name As String = ""
    Try
        If Request.Files.Count > 0 Then
            For Each uploaded_file As String In Request.Files
                Dim fileContent = Request.Files(uploaded_file)
                If fileContent IsNot Nothing AndAlso fileContent.ContentLength > 0 Then
                    Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploaded_file)
                    _url_file_name = "/Images/users/" + fileName
                    fileContent.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/users"), fileName))
                    ws_masters.update_item_image(_url_file_name, item_id)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Return Json("No Selected File", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        End If
    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
        Return Json("Upload failed", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Try
    Return Json(_url_file_name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

items.js

```
function load_item_list() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/master/item_list?item_id=0",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var vdatatable = $("#tbl_items").DataTable();
            vdatatable.clear();
            vdatatable.draw();
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                vdatatable.row.add(["<img src='"+ item.thumb_path + "' class='img-thumbnail img-responsive thumb' style='width:50px;' />", "<a href='#' onClick='item_details(\"" + item.item_id + "\");'>" + item.item_code + "</a>", item.item_desc, item.price, item.uom_code]).draw();
            });
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            console.log(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Please answer this in detailed. Just new on this approach. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is where you need to focus your debugging efforts: `ws_masters.item_view_sel(item_id, Session("company_no"))`. As I can only guess, I'd say it could be a bad connection string.

Comment: i'm using querystring that needs item_id and company_no and then execute. It loads fast when I only get the top 100.

Comment: Only 100? There may well be some optimization you can do but also consider paging because shoving hundreds of rows at a user can be counter-productive.

Comment: i mean it loads fast when I just get the top 100 but getting all records results to request timeout. I got 3k records..

Comment: the data table I used has pagination..

Comment: Data tables don't have pagination so it's unclear what kind if pagination you are doing - it should be done server side.

Comment: Yes it does.. Look at the code of items.vbhtml.. That table is what I am talking about..

Comment: Ok, I thought you meant System.Data.DataTable